# Mod-Rewrite to a query string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to create a series of redirects for personalized urls. They need to go from a directory on my server to a more complex url on another which includes a query string based on the original url. Here is an example:

I would like to rewrite from this:
http://www.mywebsite.com/TestDirectory/John.Doe

to this:

http://their.server.com/adifferentdirectoryname/page.aspx?u=John.Doe&s=lorem&dm=purl

There will be hundreds of these personalized urls I will send out, so I need the solution to account for that so that I don't have to write this for hundreds of names.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Much Thanks!

Comment: Nothing, I have no idea....everything I found was for simplifying query strings, not creating them.

Comment: Which URL do you want users to see? Should they be redirected to the Url with the QS?

Comment: Yes, the first url is what I will give them in a printed format, the simple one. The second is what that url should be directed to, with the QS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something [*like* this](http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/sitemanagement/urlrewriting.html#usingregularexpressions):

```
RewriteRule ^TestDirectory/(\w+\.\w+)$ foo.aspx?u=$1 [R]
```

The regex `\w+\.\w+` matches a word, a dot, and another word. The `$1` is replaced with the captured string from the regex. The `[R]` means to actually redirect the user.

These rules are tough to get just right so I recommend reading through [some examples](http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/sitemanagement/urlrewriting.html#usingregularexpressions).